# How can I draw a part of a texture in slick2d?

Tags: opengl, java, textures, slick

I know the method for drawing a region of a texture in slick2d:

```
image.draw(x, y, srcX, srcY, srcX2, srcY2);
```

But I have no idea how the texture coordinates work. To draw a region of `x:16, y:16, width:32, height:16` from a texture. I tried:

```
image.draw(0, 0, 16, 16, 32, 16);
```

and I have tried many other things with no luck. All I get is weirdly cropped and stretched images. Help?

Comment: it goes x position on screen, y position, then the texture coordinates of left, top, right, bottom
http://slick.ninjacave.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/Image.html#draw%28float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float%29

Comment: I wrote a sprite retrieval class... Maybe try that? http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/47675/spritesheet-in-slick2d-or-lwjgl/47713#47713

Comment: @nhydock I already tried that and even looked at that page but it didn't work. It doesn't really seem like you know what you're talking about

Comment: @Savlon Yeah but I already have the code to load slick2d images and I just want to know how this method works.

Comment: "weirdly cropped and stretched images" is a bit of a vague and unhelpful descriptor without a screenshot

Comment: @nhydock So I took an `Image`. I got the window set up. I rendered the image with that method and tried the parameters that you told me to use and the image looked more like a 16x16 image that was scaled to 100 pixels. I just need to know how texture coordinates in slick2d works.

Comment: Post a screenshot so we can see what your issue is... The coordinate system has already been explained to you and you insulted him when there was no need at all... If you come on this site asking for help and get it, don't throw it back in the publishers face... They didn't have to take the time out of their day to answer your question but they did.

Comment: @Savlon Yeah the coordinate system was explained but I don't think its correct. It just seems like he/she doesn't know much about slick and just googled it. Like I want advice from people who have experience with what I'm asking about. If they don't, then chances are I'm not going to get much help, thats all. I wouldn't answer someone whos asking how to do something I have no experience with.

Comment: The problem is if you're just using (x, y, srcX, srcY, srcX2, srcY2) it'll use the src texture coordinates but it'll stretch it to the same size as the entire image. Slick2D works much like Java2d. If you don't want it to stretch but you want to crop then you'll want to use http://slick.ninjacave.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/Image.html#draw%28float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float%29 and use it as image.draw(0, 0, 32, 16, 16, 16, 48, 32)